# After inserting data into mysql, its showing IterableWrapper(non-empty Iterator) instead of String in Spark Java

Tags: java, mysql, apache-spark

**I am trying to insert String in mysql database through foreachpartition, but after inserting it, it is showing IterableWrapper(non-empty Iterator) instead of String.**

```
            public class Insert {
            transient static SparkConf ss;
            transient static JavaSparkContext spc;
             public static void main(String gg[]) 
            {

              ss=new SparkConf().setAppName("insert").setMaster("local");

             spc=new JavaSparkContext(ss);

                JavaRDD<String> rbm=spc.textFile("/home/amd/gg/out5/aa");
                // DataFrame jdbcDF =sqlContext.jdbc(options.get("url"),options.get("dbtable"));

                // System.out.println("Data------------------->" + jdbcDF.toJSON().first());






            try {
                rbm.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>()   {
                public void call(Iterator<String> x) throws Exception {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                {

                    Connection conn= (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing","root","amd@123");

                    PreparedStatement del = (PreparedStatement) conn.prepareStatement ("INSERT INTO rtl (rtl_s) VALUES(?)");
                    while (x.hasNext()) {
```

**// Here it is showing the correct String but in mysql it is showing different thing.**

```
                 String y=x.next();
                System.out.println(x);

                            del.setString(1, y);            
                            del.executeUpdate();
                       }
            **//After inserting data to mysql it is giving IteratorWrapper instead of String.**
                    conn.close();
                }

                        }

                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }


     **I am getting the IterableWrapper(non-empty Iterator) in mysql database instead of String.**
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I was getting the error, because some RDD was empty.
Then you need to use coalesce(1)....